# Error while executing SSIS package from JOB

Tags: ssis

Message

> Executed as user: UKDBT91DB05V\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   14:58:34  Error: 2013-04-01 14:58:34.45     Code: 0xC0016016
>   Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node
>   "DTS:Property" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in
>   specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this
>   information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error.
>   Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error:
>   2013-04-01 14:58:34.76     Code: 0xC001000E     Source:
>   ReceiveDGDinformation      Description: The connection "stock" is not
>   found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the
>   specific connection element is not found.  End Error  Error:
>   2013-04-01 14:58:34.80     Code: 0xC0202009     Source:
>   ReceiveDGDinformation Connection manager "Stock"     Description: SSIS
>   Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80040E4D.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
>   SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description:
>   "Login failed for user 'DOTCOM\UKDBT91DB05V$'.".  End Error  Error:
>   2013-04-01 14:58:34.80     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Populate
>   Staginng Table Populate DGD Staging table [34]     Description: SSIS
>   Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Stock" failed
>   with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call
>   failed.  End Error  Error: 2013-04-01 14:58:34.80     Code: 0xC0047017
>   Source: Populate Staginng Table SSIS.Pipeline     Description:
>   component "Populate DGD Staging table" (34) failed validation and
>   returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2013-04-01
>   14:58:34.80     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Populate Staginng Table
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed
>   validation.  End Error  Error: 2013-04-01 14:58:34.80     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: Populate Staginng Table      Description: There
>   were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  14:58:34  Finished:
>   14:58:34  Elapsed:  0.624 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The
>   step failed.

Meaningful bits of the error message

- Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Property" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error
- Login failed for user 'DOTCOM\UKDBT91DB05V$'

Comment: You are starting the package from a SQL Agent job - what parameters are you setting? Is the package actually encrypted? Are you using a username and password to connect to the Stock database or does the Connection Manager use SSPI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a problem with your ProtectionLevel setting and how you are configuring the job.

If ProtectionLevel is at the default "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" setting, then the development environment is encrypting things like your connection string database password using a key that depends on the user who is doing the development.  After you deploy it to the production server and schedule a SQL Server Agent job, it will most likely run under a different user account, and then it will be unable to decrypt the database password.  You will get this error.

One possibility would be to make sure the development user and the job execution user are the same user account, but this is not a good idea.  Usually you want your production user accounts to be separate from your development user accounts.

Instead, you should set ProtectionLevel to "DontSaveSensitive".  Then the password won't get saved with the SSIS package at all.  You create a configuration file for the connection string, but the password won't get saved to the configuration file either.  You will have to edit the configuration file manually if you want it to include a password.  But the best way to do this is to configure the password when you schedule the job that executes the SSIS package.  That keeps the password in a safe place, and it isn't floating around all over the place with the SSIS package.

Some useful links [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9607471f-ef30-4829-a61a-e5e11c209a56) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;904800).

Good luck!

Comment: This answer could be improved if it would explain how to create the configuration file and how to edit it.