# SSIS connection manager login fails

Tags: database, ssis

I have an SSIS project wherein I defined a Data Source (provider: Native OLE DB/Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server). When I open this up manually and hit the button "test connection" all works fine. The connection manager can access the DB using the connection string, user and password.

Now I have an SSIS package where I created a connection manager based on this data source ("new connection from data source...").

In the package control flow I have an SQL task which has connection type OLE DB and connection is set to my connection manager within this very package. The task fires some update statement to the database, noting fancy at all.

Now when I debug the whole thing I always get the same error:

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
>   Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available. Source:
>   "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80040E4D
>   Description: "Login failed for user 'myUser'."

FYI: myUser equals the user name I have for my database.

So my question is: what am I missing here? I really can't see what's wrong here. I'm really stuck here. Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ddi you run the package in BIDS or though SQL server Agent?

Comment: In BIDS I simply hit F5 (Start Debugging)

Comment: Do you have any other package in your solution?. Try -> right click on your package and click execute package option.

Comment: Yes, there are also other packages. When I do as you say I still get the same error message...

Comment: Have you created any configuration file ? and what is `Package Protection Level` set to ?

Comment: Package configurations are disabled and Protection Level is DontSaveSensitive. (But also when I change it to EnrcyptSensitiveWithUserKey or EnryptSensitiveWithPassword it still doesn't work)

Comment: Check this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/35139786-12bd-424a-9a60-27b5de981cd6

Comment: My data source connection manager already uses sql server authentication. And as I mentioned when I test it with the stated user and pw it does succeed.

Comment: Can u create a configuration file and use `Dont save sensitive` and explicitly mention the password in XML?

Comment: But when we run through BIDS we don't need configuration file right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ProtectionLevel "DontSaveSensitive" means the password won't get saved with the SSIS package at all.  The reason SSIS does this is so that the password isn't floating around where someone else could get it.

So when you type in the password and hit the button "test connection" it all works fine.  But when you run in debug mode (or in production), you don't have a password.  Therefore, of course, the login fails.

This is why you need a configuration file.  [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745281/error-while-executing-ssis-package-from-job/15747606#15747606):

> You create a configuration file for the connection string, but the
>   password won't get saved to the configuration file either. You will
>   have to edit the configuration file manually if you want it to include
>   a password. But the best way to do this is to configure the password
>   when you schedule the job that executes the SSIS package. That keeps
>   the password in a safe place, and it isn't floating around all over
>   the place with the SSIS package.

While you are debugging, of course, you need a configuration file that has the password manually typed into it.  But that configuration file doesn't go with the package when it's deployed to production.  The production config file should have a blank password.  The password should live in the scheduled job that executes the package.

Comment: Some questions for my understanding: I have DontSaveSensitive but in my data source connection manager there is actually a user and password stored as well as save my password option is selected. Regarding your answer, isn't that a conflict? Also: why doesn't it then work when I change to EnrcyptSensitiveWithUserKey or EnryptSensitiveWithPassword? Last but not least: I simply want to test my package if it runs fine. How can I do so in the quickest way?

Comment: It looks like it's saving the userid and password, but it's not.  It'll keep it around for a while after you typed it in to test the connection, so it looks like it's working, but then it stops working.  It's confusing.  But that's the way SSIS does it.  The encryption options are a different story, and are even less easy to use.  Add a config file, and edit the XML manually to put in the password.

Comment: Actually you don't need a configuration file while runs through BIDS. If you reopened your package then you need to give your password again if your protection level is "don't save sensitive". But in your case seems like you may missed something. See if there any other connection managers are available in your package. and check if you selected the same connection manager which you tested.

Comment: So if actually you don't need a configuration file, how do you get around this problem?

Comment: @SelectDistinct - if you're scheduling execution through SQL Server Agent, you may be able to set protection levels and passwords when you are setting up the Job to execute the SSIS package.  I haven't tried it in the most recent versions of SQL Server, but I think in some of the earlier versions you only got access to these properties when you already had a configuration file for them.  So sometimes I have actually set up a dummy configuration file for a few properties merely so that I would be able to set those properties at the SQL Server Job level.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around that problem in BIDS.

1) First of all if you don't have configuration file and in your connection manager you are using a sql server authentication then you will get a red cross in ole db source or destination tasks. It won't happen in execute sql tasks because the ole db source and destination tasks actually have to run a select * from table query to get you the list of tables to select from. Since password is not saved it will throw you an error.

2) If you do have a configuration file you will still face the similar problem. But with configuration file you can edit and manually insert password. It worked for me. The ole db source and destination tasks were not showing any red cross.