# Error Execution Package SSIS from SQL Server Agent, but runs from catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS Package deployed in the Integration Service Catalogs of Sql Server 2014. When I run the package from the catalogs all works perfectly, the sql server session works with an authentication windows. I have created a job in Agent Sql Server to run this package, I am the owner of the job and I have admin rights on Sql Server, the step that runs the package is run as a service account SQL Server Agent. But when running the job it crashes with the following error:

> Load FTP file Qc: Error: The directory is not specified in the User Connection Manager::DownloadDirectoryQc.

But it is beautiful and well otherwise it would not work catalog. Would anyone have a reason for what is causing this problem?

Comment: May be you can create a sql server agent proxy account and configure the Run as in the job to use sql server agent proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a configuration file that the job can use to find connection manager information, such as the download directory path.  This information may be available in your environment when you run from the catalog in SSMS, but isn't available to the job when it runs.  Configuration files help with this problem.  (Also, see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745281/error-while-executing-ssis-package-from-job/15747606#15747606)).