# SSIS Visual Studios 2019 . Oracle Connection . Manual package execution via DTExec

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

Problem: Hi SO community. Trying to execute a VS_2019 package that I can execute while in BIDS. Ran though all the specs including converting the package to
1) Package deployment mode
2) Converted the package to run in 32-bit mode
3) Finally, creating a config file to store the Oracle server credentials in
using this url: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-the-command-line-or-a-batch-file
4) Build the project no issues ; i.e. zero erros.
What I have tried:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /file "C:\Users\name\Desktop\SSIS_Local\JDA_Test\bin\Development\OrderAccuracy.dtsx" /config "C:\Users\name\Desktop\SSIS_Local\JDA_Test\JDA_PackageDeployment_Config.dtsConfig"

AND

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /file "C:\Users\name\Desktop\SSIS_Local\JDA_Test\bin\Development\OrderAccuracy.dtsx" /config "C:\Users\name\Desktop\SSIS_Local\JDA_Test\JDA_PackageDeployment_Config.dtsConfig"

and both give me the error: **The SSIS runtime version 15.0.2000.5 is too low for this Oracle connector. Please install a newer version of SSIS (later than SQL Server 2019 RTM).
End Error**

Finally: internals of config file are:
SERVER=0.0.025.183:1521/DB;USERNAME=PB;WINAUTH=0;data source=0.0.225.183:1521/db;user id=pb;password=kuttp8x2bRRE;

So any help or direction would be great. Please feel free to ask any further questions.
I'm NOT even connecting to a SQL Server 2019. My source is Oracle. And my destination is going to be a flat file. This data will go into Snowflake database. But ETL tool used to connect to Oracle is SSIS.
[image: VM_SQL_Services_Stopped]
[image: Server_Specs_on_VM]
[image: 32Bit_Ver_Manual_vs_Auto]

[image: 64Bit_Ver_Manual_vs_Auto]

Comment: The last part about config files I'm doing the same "DoNotSaveSensitive" as package protection level; hence the config file. Around this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745281/error-while-executing-ssis-package-from-job

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to install the latest SQL Server 2019 update located here:
https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fhelp%2F4548597%2Fcumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2019&data=02%7C01%7Cv-sagkal%40microsoft.com%7C69a0e5d79ceb4ae3e20608d7daec4509%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637218580624686059&sdata=4avejidj69V2tJoQ5CWAaqIX9SCaHohWD%2F4we5hEGsg%3D&reserved=0

Package now runs with both 32-bit and 64-bit DTSExec versions. Password for source is stored in a config file and solution is on 'package deployment mode' . 
Solution for anyone who runs into this issue in future.